# Akka IO TCP receive data

Tags: tcp, io, akka

I'm reading documentation about [Using TCP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/io-tcp.html) and trying to uderstand how simple TCP receives data from server. Let's the server sends stream of data to every connected client.

```
    case Received(data) => // do some with data, where data: ByteString
```

So what is `data`. What is the size of the data in Bytes? I mean clients continuously receives some data. How many bytes does every such `data` contain? Where is it configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's arbitrary and not configured anywhere. You get whatever you haven't gotten already that the implementation happened to have to give you at the time it decided to give you some data.

A typical way to handle such a notification is as follows:

1. If we had any saved data from the last notification, append the new data onto the end of the saved data.
2. If we don't have an entire message according to the protocol we are implementing, save any remaining data for the next notification, re-arm notifications, and stop.
3. Process the message.
4. If we have no leftover data (that is, we had exactly one application message and not a byte more), note that the buffer is empty, re-arm notifications, and stop.
5. Go to step 2 with the leftover data.